# Quotient of functions

Tags: vector-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Define the vector space $V = \{\text{functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$}\}$ and the subpsace $U \subset V$ by $U = \{\text{functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid f(0) = 0$}\}$. Prove that the quotient $V/U$ is finite-dimensional and compute $\dim (V/U)$.

I cannot figure out how to get started. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Prove that $V/U\simeq \Bbb R$ by considering the evaluation at $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by considering the evaluation at $0$.

Comment: Consider the linear functional $V\ni f\longmapsto f(0)\in\Bbb R$